# Ionic multiple splash screens

Tags: android, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I'm building an application with Ionic v1 and using the [cordova splash-screen plug-in](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).
I need to show a splash screen form a fixed set of images each time the app starts.

Is there any way, clean or hackish to get multiple splash-screens?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is not possible with cordova. Possibly native implementation could help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Cordova Splash Screen plugin but you can try this.

First we will create array of images :

`$rootScope.image = ["img1.png","img2.png"];`

And set/reset index for picking image :

`if(localStorage.getItem('sliderIndex')==null || localStorage.getItem('sliderIndex')==undefined || localStorage.getItem('sliderIndex')==5)
      localStorage.setItem('sliderIndex',0);`

Here is your view page

```
<img src="img/{{image[imgIndex]}}" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

And set imgIndex's value :

```
$scope.imgIndex = localStorage.getItem('sliderIndex');
```

And navigate the page after 3 sec, incrementing the index value :

```
$timeout(function() {
  $location.path("/app/search");
  var data = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('sliderIndex'))+1;
  localStorage.setItem('sliderIndex',data);},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain image displayed on splash screen in Local storage.

e.g suppose images array contains [1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png,5.png]
so when if I displayed 1.png first time then will save that in local storage and when next time splash screen gets appeared check that local storage and increment it by 1 and so on... till last image,if on last image set first image again

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but unfortunately to implement this the app must be ready, then there's a black screen before this images are shown.